# Wait for second mouse click on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm playing around with Tkinter and Python and I would like to click on two positions on a canvas and then draw a line between the two points.

Using the .bind() method, I can easily call a function which takes the position of the cursor and sets the first point, but I don't know how to make the function wait for the second mouse click. There are of course workarounds, but I'd like to know if I can make a function wait indefinitely until the second click.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to wait. On the first click set a flag, on the second click examine the flag

```
class Example(...):
    def __init__(...):
        self.first_coord = None
        ...
        canvas.bind("<1>", self.on_click)
    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.first_coord is None:
            self.first_coord = (event.x, event.y)
        else:
            second_coord = (event.x, event.y)
            <draw the line here>
            self.first_coord = None
```

Comment: @ Bryan: should be `else:`, not `elee:`, correct? clear for me but for better reading / completely correct code, this would need one change.